# Same type, different namespace.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nhibernate

So I'm trying to convert an entity into a DTO using the **exact same type**.  Both types (classes) are the exact same except they are in **different namespaces.**

Should I need to cast them when I reference either one from the other namespace?

Or should VS automatically know and recognize they are the exact same although in different files?

Thanks

Comment: Different namespace = different type. VS cannot (and certainly should not) automagically figure out your intent in this case. You'll need to provide a conversion/cast operator. Take a look at [C# Conversion Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx)

Comment: Just try it and you'll know the answer ...

Comment: The problem with the question is that you are assuming what you set out to ask about.  Two types that differ in their namespace are different types *because* they are in different namespaces. The notion that two types are "the same but in different namespaces" is self-contradictory.

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace SomeInternetShoppingSite
{
     public class Client
     {
          public int Id { get; }
          public sprint FirstName { get; }
          ...
     }
}

namespace SomeOnlineBankingSite
{
     public class Client
     {
          public int Id { get; }
          public sprint FirstName { get; }
          ...
     }   
}
```

Do you really think the following should be legal?

```
var bankClient = new SomeOnlineBankingSite.Client(...);
var shoppingClient = (SomeInternetShoppingSite.Client)bankClient;
```

Allthough both classes are identical they are two completely different abstractions of two very distinct concepts. Even if the compiler can easily enough figure out that the type definitions are the same, it has no right to allow an explicit or implicit conversion between the two; only the authors of the classes have the right to allow that conversion if they so wish to, implementing a cast operator, a static factory method or what have you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you're describing is [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). The closest C# equivalent is the "dynamic" keyword but I don't think that's exactly what you're asking for.

As others have pointed out, C# does *not*, in general, follow the typing model you've described and you probably wouldn't *want* it to. As InBetween's example shows, there's a big difference between "same name," "same interface," and "same *meaning*."

To answer the question more directly, first, I seriously question the wisdom of having two identical classes in separate namespaces - it seems like a pretty clear violation of the [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principal. With that said, if define an implicit conversion between them that should allow you to use them more or less interchangeably (although the downside to that is it could get confusing which of the two objects you're referring to; I'm inclined to say that it's a bad practice based on that fact along).